# How to create a project using Android Studio 3.5.2 w/o AS generating the layout file?

Tags: android-studio

In [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com) 'Exercise: Create the AboutMe Project' which is using Android Studio Version 3.2 Beta 4 it has one uncheck the "Generate Layout File".

[image: AS 3.2create empty activity]

When I use Android Studio Version 3.5.2,

[image: AS 3.5.2 version info]

I do:

```
File>New Project>Choose Your Project>Empty Activity>Next
```

[image: AS 3.5.2 Create your project]

which does not have the check box.

The resulting project has a layout file. How do I use AS 3.5.2 to create the project w/o the layout file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with AS 4.0. I just edited the activity_main.xml to look like the one in the course and that worked.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</LinearLayout>
```